# Unable to get Number of Comments

Tags: wordpress, drupal, joomla, rss, feed

I' am using RSS Feeds generated from **WordPress Blogs** to fetch some Information. WordPress is just too good in providing comprehensive information about a Post and it is quite easy to extract *Number of Comments* for a Post in RSS Feed. Now the problem is that I didn't find any way to get *Number of Comments* from RSS Feeds generated by **Drupal** and **Joomla Blogs**.

Is there any way to do this?

Any help would be really appriciated.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using feedburner by google? feedburner.google.com/ I have in the past had the same issue and for some reason running it through feedburner first seemed to help.

Comment: Thanks Matt for your reply. Sorry! Matt I didn't get your point. I' am fetching information from third-party RSS Feeds and I don't want to burn them on the Fly.

It will be really kind of you if you please! elaborate your answer with an example so that if I have missed your point it can help me.

Thanks. :-)

Answer (score 0):

Here is a cool Drupal module that may help you. If your rss field is not generated by views. First Move it into views. Then use this module to output the comment count as a field

http://drupal.org/project/views_rss

Otherwise you'll need to do some theme overrides in the template layer. Drupal does not provide a default method for customizing the core rss feed.

Comment: Thanks Danielson for your answer. My Problem is a bit different. I' am fetching information from third-party Blogs and I' am not authorized to do customization on their RSS Feeds. ;-)

Comment: I think your out of luck then. The information just isn't in the feed by default. You might be able to crawl the pages the rss feed points to for the number of comments. The individual node page usually have a comment count on them somewhere. A bash script wget | sed "some comment identifier" would probably do the task.